# Start-Process "git" returns strange 129 exit code

Tags: git, bash, powershell

In Bash

```
$ git status > /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Same repository in Powershell

```
$> (Start-Process git -ArgumentList="status" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
129
```

What is going on here, what `129` means and why it is not equal to `0` and how to get it right?

Comment: http://errordecoder.com/system-error-codes/1/code-129.html

Comment: Also, if you want the status of your repository in PowerShell, you might check out https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git or https://github.com/ethomson/gitpowershell

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you specify the arguments to `git` incorrectly (and needs to print its usage) it will exit with error code 129:

```
C:\Temp>git status --asdf
error: unknown option `asdf`
usage: git status [options] [--] <filepattern>...

    .... help is printed here ....

C:\Temp>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
129
```

Is it possible that you are passing the commands through PowerShell incorrectly?  (Eg, is `-Wait -Passthrough` being delivered to `git-status`?)

You could avoid passing arguments entirely by calling the `git-status` command instead of calling `git` with the `status` argument.

Comment: there is a problem with calling `git-status`: "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ Well, you may need to specify the full path, or put the git `libexec` directory in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Same thing when calling [git add --pathspec-from-file=file.txt] on git 2.19.1.4 which does not support this option.