# GitPython post-receive git hook script fails after push

Tags: python, git

I have a client-side post-receive git hook that runs a Python script. The script uses GitPython to do a diff between HEAD and HEAD~1, figure out the names of files that have been changed, and then compose a tweet that updates followers about the change.

The hook itself is just a shell script that runs `python wikitweet.py`, where the Python script does the heavy lifting.

When I run the Python script on the remote side after a push, everything works fine. But when I push from the local side, I get the following error:

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/home/wcm1/bin/wikitweet.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:     most_recent_diff = repo.head.commit.diff('HEAD~1')
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/git/diff.py", line 111, in diff
remote:     proc.wait()
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 309, in wait
remote:     raise GitCommandError(self.args, status, self.proc.stderr.read())
remote: git.exc.GitCommandError: 'git diff c43a0b831612eb97f097458816d41aaa0506147d HEAD~1 --abbrev=40 --full-index -M --raw --no-color' returned with exit code 129
remote: stderr: 'usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
remote: '
```

After which the push to master and update of working of copy completes just fine. I can tell from the commit hash in that error message that the script is successfully getting the new HEAD commit, so it doesn't seem to be an issue (I don't think) of when the hook is being run.

I'm guessing that I'm either misunderstanding hooks, or doing something wrong in my Python script, but am having difficulty understanding why it runs on the remote side but fails after push. Here are the relevant lines in `wikitweet.py` that seem to be causing problems:

```
repo = git.Repo('/path/to/repo')

most_recent_diff = repo.head.commit.diff('HEAD~1')
changed_files = []
for x in most_recent_diff:
    if x.a_blob.path not in changed_files:
       changed_files.append(x.a_blob.path)
    if x.b_blob is not None and x.b_blob.path not in changed_files:
       changed_files.append(x.b_blob.path)

    [...]
```

I also have different versions of Python running on remote and local, though I don't see why that would cause a problem.

Comment: The git error code 129 indicates incorrect arguments (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733440/start-process-git-returns-strange-129-exit-code). The Python module seems to be calling the git shell command directly rather than using a git library bindings. Which version of git is running on the remote? Maybe that version of git does not accept the same command flags as the version you have running locally.

Comment: Local version is 1.7.5.4. Remote version is 1.7.12.1.382.gb0576a6. Maybe I should look into updating local one.

Comment: It looks like if I run `git diff c43a0b831612eb97f097458816d41aaa0506147d HEAD~1 --abbrev=40 --full-index -M --raw --no-color` manually from within the directory containing the repo, it works on both the local and remote sides, but if I run it outside of the directory, I get the stderr message. Could that be a problem here? Maybe there's a git environment variable somewhere that needs to be reset? I tried just adding a `cd` to the directory in the `post-receive` script, but to no avail.

Comment: I have the hunch that it is related to the environment as well. You could try to execute `export` in bash to see what kind of environment you have in the post-receive hook, and compare that to the standard shell environment. In theory, you can debug this using a shell script, which should also allow you to reproduce the issue GitPython encounters. After all, it just executes the git command, inheriting the parent process' environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a standard error because of an environment variable that git sets when using a `post-receive` hook. The solution was to add this line to my hook:

```
unset GIT_DIR
```

This page offers some [helpful tips about hooks and environment variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) that helped me figure out the problem.